# How to merge rows for the same month in the same year using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is organised as below:

```
Date           combined_news
2008-09-12     []
2008-09-15     []
...            ...
2016-12-25     []
```

I wanted to modify this data frame such that all news items for a particular month are in a single row, for each year.

```
Date           combined_news
2008-09        [], []
2008-10        []
...            ...
2016-12        []
```

So far, I tried using

```
news_data = news_data.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.month))['combined_news'].apply(''.join)
```

But that gives me ***'int' object has no attribute 'year'*** error.

Comment: What is the type of your Date column?

Comment: are those `list`s in `'combined_news'` column?

Comment: Yes, they are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `pandas.TimeGrouper` after making sure you have a datetime index. Then you could do something like

```
news_data.index = news_data.Date
news_data = news_data\.
    groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('M'))\.
    agg({'combined_news': ''.join})
```

Comment: While it groups, it doesn't combine the news items by the right months. For instance, a news item from October shows up in January.

Comment: That might mean that the datetimes you constructed were not parsed correctly. How did you create the `Date` column?

Comment: `news_data = pd.read_csv("Combined_News_DJIA.csv", header=0)

news_data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(news_data['Date'])`

Comment: There has definitely been an issue in the parsing. It seems, in some places, the day has been parsed as the month and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `news_data`

```
news_data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(combined_news=[[]] * 100),
    pd.date_range('2016-04-01', periods=100)
)
```

---

You can `resample` + `apply(list)` + `to_period`

```
n1 = news_data.resample('M').combined_news.apply(list)
n1.index = n1.index.to_period('M')

print(n1)

2016-04    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
2016-05    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
2016-06    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
2016-07                 [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
Freq: M, Name: combined_news, dtype: object
```

Comment: While it groups, it doesn't combine the news items by the right months. For instance, a news item from October shows up in January.